# how to get parent id of a document in Elasticsearch in java？

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with parent-child relationship in Elasticsearch.I do a search action in java client and get the child documents .There are `getId()`、`getIndex()`、`getType()`、`getSource()` methods for using，but no `getParent()`.How can I get the parent id in java？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over the response hits, you can use the `SearchHit.field("_parent")` method in order to retrieve the id of the parent document.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().execute().actionGet();
for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits().getHits()) {
    SearchHitField parent = hit.field("_parent");
}
```

Comment: I have another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738573/how-to-know-if-a-type-of-a-index-has-parent-or-child-relationship-in-elasticsear