# How to know if a type of a index has parent or child relationship in Elasticsearch in java?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with *parent-child* relationship in **Elasticsearch**. When I do *hasParentQuery* or *hasChildQuery*, I need to know if a type of an index has  *parent-child* relationship. Is it possible to achieve that, using Java client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GetMappingsRequest getRequest = new  GetMappingsRequest().indices("indexname");
GetMappingsResponse cs = client.admin().indices().getMappings(getRequest).get();
ImmutableOpenMap<String, MappingMetaData> mappingStr = cs.mappings().get("indexname");
for (ObjectObjectCursor<String, MappingMetaData> c : mappingStr) {
            Map m = (Map) c.value.getSourceAsMap().get("_parent");
            if (m != null) {
                if (typeName.equals(m.get("type")))
                    types.add(c.key);
            }

}
if(types.size>0){
  return true;
}else{
 return false;
}
```